# How To Add <math.h> header in CLion

Tags: clion, math.h

I'm New to CLion. I have created a project which name is *test12* and which file name is *avs.c*.

I'm Getting an Error of type `Undefined reference 'sqrt'`

*CMakeListsta.txt* is :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)
project (test12 C)
set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99)
add_executable(test12 avs.c)
```

What changes should I do to make CMAKELISTS use *math.h* header in *CLion*?

Comment: I edited the question so as to have a good format but it was hard to understand the question by itself. Please make sure to edit the question and make it clear enough

Comment: I'm getting error error undefined reference 'sqrt'  when i use math.h header. How to make this work(math.h) in Clion?

Comment: Please provide avs.c file showing your code. This does not sound like a cmake issue.

Comment: #include<stdio.h> #include<math.h> void main() { int a=25,b; b=sqrt(a); printf("%d",b);}

Answer (score 2):

It looks like `math.h`is not enabled in CLion, so you need to enable it! [Source here](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206607085-CLion-Enabling-math-h-for-C-projects).

1. add `#include <math.h>`
2. add target_link_libraries( m) in CMakeLists.txt

The second command allows you to link with libm for the math functions.

Adding this to your makefile! (**Check** the source I gave you!!)

```
target_link_libraries(log m)
```